# can't download OS Elementary loki

Tags: download

I bought the system but the link to download doesn't work. I click and nothing happen. I mean the download doesn't start.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, you paid money here, [eOS home page](https://elementary.io/)

but you did not get to download the elementary OS distro?

Thanks for your support. 
Just go back and put a zero in the custom amount field. You should now see a download button that works.